# Changing variables in differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I convert $$\frac {d^2\eta}{dr^2} \tag{1}$$ to $$\frac {d^2\sigma(u)}{du^2}-\frac{3}{4}u^{-2}\sigma(u) \tag{2}$$ by introducing the variable $$u=r^{1/2}$$ and the function $$\sigma(u)=u^{-1/2}\eta(r)$$

Comment: Eq.(1) needs to be an equation, so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from:
$$\frac {d\eta}{dr}=\frac {d\eta}{du}\frac {du}{dr} $$
$$\frac {d^2\eta}{dr^2}=\frac {d}{dr}\left(\frac {d\eta}{du}\frac {du}{dr}\right) $$
Differentiate:
$$\frac {d^2\eta}{dr^2}=\frac {d\eta}{du}\frac {d^2u}{dr^2} +\frac {d^2\eta}{du^2}\left(\frac {du}{dr}\right)^2$$

$$\frac {d^2\eta}{dr^2}=\frac {d}{du}\left ( \sigma(u)u^{1/2} \right )\frac {d^2u}{dr^2} +\frac {d^2}{du^2}\left ( \sigma(u)u^{1/2} \right )\left(\frac {du}{dr}\right)^2$$

You need to calculate $\frac {du}{dr}$:
$$\frac {du}{dr}=\frac {dr^{1/2}}{dr}=\frac 12r^{-1/2}=\frac 1{2u}$$
$$\frac {d^2u}{dr^2}=\frac 12\frac {dr^{-1/2}}{dr}=-\frac 14r^{-3/2}=-\frac 1{4u^3}$$

Comment: Thanks, But I was confused, can you write the final result?

Comment: I added some lines @Wisdom